# CSS transition animation not working

Tags: html, css, animation, css-transitions

This is my code and I am trying to make the label float while the input box is focused, which is similar to angular material animation. I succeeded with the logic but the animation doesn't seems to work.

I am using pure CSS and HTML.

```css
.space {
  padding: 5px;
  margin-top: 30px;
}
.space .form_input {
  display: inline-block;
}
.space .form_input input {
  border: none;
  border-bottom: solid thin #d6d6d6;
  background: none;
  position: absolute;
  box-shadow: initial;
}
.space .form_input input:focus {
  border: none;
  border-bottom: solid thin #d6d6d6;
  outline: none;
}
.space .form_input input:focus + label {
  transition: all 0.7s ease-out;
  top: -20px;
}
.space .form_input input:valid + label {
  top: -20px;
}
.space .form_input input[value=""] + label {
  border: green;
}
.space .form_input input ~ label {
  -webkit-transition: all 0.7s ease-out;
  -moz-transition: all 0.7s ease-out;
  -ms-transition: all 0.7s ease-out;
  -o-transition: all 0.7s ease-out;
  transition: all 0.7s ease-out;
  pointer-events: none;
  color: red;
  position: relative;
}
```

```html
<form class='space'>
 <div class='form_input'>
  <input name='email' id='email' required>
  <label for='email'> Email: </label>
 </div>
</form>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to define the initial position of animation (without focus) using...

`.space .form_input input ~ label {top: 0;}`

```css
.space {
  padding: 5px;
  margin-top: 30px;
}
.space .form_input {
  display: inline-block;
}

.space .form_input input {
  border: none;
  border-bottom: solid thin #d6d6d6;
  background: none;
  position: absolute;
  box-shadow: initial;
}
.space .form_input input:focus {
  border: none;
  border-bottom: solid thin #d6d6d6;
  outline: none;
}
.space .form_input input:focus + label {
  transition: all 0.7s ease-out;
  top: -20px;
}
.space .form_input input:valid + label {
  top: -20px;
}
.space .form_input input[value=""] + label {
  border: green;
}
.space .form_input input ~ label {
  transition: all 0.7s ease-out;
  pointer-events: none;
  color: red;
  position: relative;
  top: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://leaverou.github.io/prefixfree/prefixfree.js"></script>

<form class="space">
  <div class="form_input">
    <input id="email" name="email" required="" />
    <label for="email"> Email: </label>
  </div>
</form>
```

Answer (score 1):

**Weave:** http://kodeweave.sourceforge.net/editor/#f364e158b2c7212831b82ef2a8460f93

Here's another way. You can [display](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/display) the label as a [block element](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/d/display/) and use [transform](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transform) to move it.

**NOTE:** I'm using [Prefix-Free](https://leaverou.github.io/prefixfree) so you don't have to call vendor prefix's in your CSS. (Along with [Normalize](https://necolas.github.io/normalize.css) for CSS cross browser compatibility)

```css
.space {
  padding: 5px;
  margin-top: 30px;
}
.space .form_input {
  display: inline-block;
}
.space .form_input input {
  border: none;
  border-bottom: solid thin #d6d6d6;
  background: none;
  position: absolute;
  box-shadow: initial;
  transition: all 0.7s ease-out;
}
.space .form_input input ~ label {
  transition: all 0.7s ease-out;
  pointer-events: none;
  color: red;
  position: relative;
  display: block;
}
.space .form_input input:focus {
  border: none;
  border-bottom: solid thin #d6d6d6;
  outline: none;
}
.space .form_input input:focus ~ label {
  transform: translate(0,-20px);
}
.space .form_input input:valid + label {
  top: -20px;
}
.space .form_input input[value=""] + label {
  border: green;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://necolas.github.io/normalize.css/4.1.1/normalize.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://leaverou.github.io/prefixfree/prefixfree.js"></script>

<form class="space">
  <div class="form_input">
    <input id="email" name="email" required="" />
    <label for="email"> Email: </label>
  </div>
</form>
```

Comment: cool,Which method is the best? as i can notice,  your method works without initializing default value on label..

Comment: [Jaromír's](http://stackoverflow.com/users/2584224/jarom%c3%adr-%c5%a0etek); however [CSS transitions and transforms use Hardware Acceleration](https://www.sitepoint.com/introduction-to-hardware-acceleration-css-animations/). You can [play with that here](http://cssanimate.com/).